# Registration with dj rest auth

Tags: reactjs, django, next.js, django-serializer, dj-rest-auth

The challenge I'm facing is when registering with dj-rest-auth, an authentication component designed for Django. When a user registers, an email is automatically sent to verify their email address. The problem is that I want to customize the appearance of that email, and so far I haven't figured out how to change the default template that dj-rest-auth uses for this purpose. The default template does not fit my needs or design preferences, and I would like to replace it with one that better suits the aesthetics of my application. Basically, I'm looking for a way to modify the email template that is sent for email verification after registration, and I'm having a hard time understanding how to make this adjustment in the dj-rest-auth framework.
I have checked the official documentation but nothing appears about this

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `templates` folder, you have to create `account/email/email_confirmation_signup_message.html` and just overwrite it with your customized content.